# How to use numeric keyboard in android notification direct reply?

Tags: android, notifications, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, remote-input

I want to use a numeric keyboard in android notification's direct reply and also want to set the input filter for it.

```
RemoteInput remoteInput =
          new RemoteInput.Builder("log").setLabel(defaultUnitBG == 1 ? "mg/dL" : "mmol").build();

      NotificationCompat.Action replyAction = null;
      NotificationCompat.Action.Builder actionBuilder =
          new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.white_circle, replyLabel,
              getLogPendingIntent(context, notificationScheduleObject, iUniqueId, notificationId));

      actionBuilder.setAllowGeneratedReplies(true);
```

Comment: i don't know if its possible with the native view but You can use customized notification instead .

Comment: can i use edit text in notification for nougat and above ?

Comment: Thats not possible(just found out) Edit text are not allowed in Remote views .

Comment: is there any way to open numeric keyboard?

Comment: I do not see a solution right now. [Read here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RemoteInput.html) and [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RemoteInput.Builder.html#setChoices(java.lang.CharSequence[])) if you have not already. Thx . Post answer if you figure out a solution for this .

Comment: Only solution i see right now is  to setChoices to remote view . And disable input. But i haven't tried it yet. So good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot will try :)